# Phantom DSL scala.NotImplementedError

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm using Phantom DSL (*v2.28.0, scala v2.12.7*) and upon each query to my database I receive the following ambiguous error:

> scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing

This doesn't happen when I use `.future()` to resolve my query, in that case queries work just fine. Also, running a `.executableQuery()` method returns a properly formatted query, which all points to my failure to build a model properly, but I don't get it what I'm doing wrong. Example queries:

Working queries:

```
db.entries.select.all.future // -> Returns a Future[ResultSet]
db.entries.select.where(_.user_id is userId).future() // -> ^
```

Failing queries:

```
db.entries.select.all.fetch // -> Err
db.entries.select.where(_.user_id is userId).fetch() // -> Err
db.entries.select.all.fetchRecord // -> Err
...
```

The same goes for paginateRecord() etc.

```
 case class Rec(
    id: UUID,
    body: String,
    time: DateTime,
    user_id: Integer
                    )

 abstract class active extends Table[active, Rec] {
    object id extends UUIDColumn with PartitionKey
    object body extends StringColumn
    object time extends DateTimeColumn
    object user_id extends IntColumn
  } 

class BasicDatabase(override val connector: CassandraConnection) extends Database[BasicDatabase](connector) {
    object entries extends active with Connector
  }
  implicit val keySpace: KeySpace = KeySpace("some_keyspace")
  implicit val session: Session = db.session
  object db extends BasicDatabase(CassandraConnector.default)
```

I'm still a newbie so any suggestions are useful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after digging into the source code, I figured out that the `fromRow()` method of the abstract class was failing so I added an override:

```
abstract class active extends Table[active, Rec] {
    object id extends TimeUUIDColumn
    object body extends StringColumn
    object time extends DateTimeColumn
    object user_id extends IntColumn

    override def fromRow(row: Row): Rec = Rec(id(row), body(row), time(row), user_id(row))
  }
```

This fixed the issue albeit I'm still not sure as to ***why*** it was failing in the first case, so any answer with appropriate explanation is still welcome.

Comment: Last time I had this error, I had a type mismatch in my case class. Did you try changing the `Integer` in your case class to `Int`?

Comment: @Wizard Yeah I did but to no avail